# Attempting to create a Python Chat System with a Lobby, Random Connect Function, and Encryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, chat, chatroom

**EDIT**
I am currently working on a chat system based on Python. I posted a question below, however have edited it to be more narrow as to what I am looking for. The system has a default function that whenever is typed in in a LOGGED_IN state, if it is not a command, the menu of the chat system is shown.
My problem is that I am working on a random function, and despite the function existing, the menu keeps appearing, I suspect the client side code to be at fault here but I cannot seem to spot my error, here is an excerpt of the code, the full file is linked below:

```
elif my_msg[0:6]=="random":
                    mysend(self.s,json.dumps({"action":"random"}))
                    allresults = json.loads(myrecv(self.s))["results"]
                    result = allresults[0]
                    user=allresults[1]
                    if result: #==True
                        self.out_msg+="Peer Found\n"
                        self.out_msg+="Connecting you now...\n\n"
                        self.out_msg+='-----------------------------------\n'
                        if self.connect_to(user) == True:
                            self.state = S_CHATTING
                            if my_msg[7:]=="anon":
                                self.out_msg += 'Connected to anonymous user. Chat away!\n\n'
                            else:
                                self.out_msg += 'Connect to ' + user + '. Chat away!\n\n'
                            self.out_msg += '-----------------------------------\n'
                        else:
                            self.out_msg += 'An error occurred, please try again.\n'
                    else:
                        self.out_msg+="Peer not found, please try again later"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am currently debugging but figured someone might see something I don't

**END EDIT**

I am currently working on a chat system based on Python with some friends just to learn more about the inner workings. Some of the key features we have been trying to implement and work with are: - a lobby (a chatroom that people can always tune into) - a random connection function (that randomly connects users together, sort of like omegle) - and encryption. This last bit does not have to be super sophisticated but if you have any recommendations how to make it better I would be happy to hear them.

The files are located [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15DL2HQTbYugOtgmaAeGgzGYg45YouO79) and I would greatly appreciate any feedback or insight into the bugs that are occurring for the lobby and random functions!

Note: the files to consider are:

- chat_lobby.py (Lobby chatroom Class)
- chat_group.py (General Group Chat Class)
- chat_server_student.py (Server side)
- client_state_machine_student.py (Client side)

Below is the random function from the server side

```
elif msg["action"]=="random":
            name=self.logged_sock2name[from_sock]
            self.availableUsers = self.group.listloners()
            self.consent = False
            while (len(self.availableUsers)>0 and self.consent != True):
                   to_name = random.choice(availableUsers)
                   to_sock = self.logged_name2sock[to_name]
                   mysend(to_sock, json.dumps({"action":"consent"}))
                   #waiting for response
                   self.consent= json.loads(myrecv(self.s))["consent"]
                   if self.consent == True:
                       result= True
                       user = self.logged_sock2name[to_sock]
                   else:
                       result = False
                       user = ""
                       self.availableUsers.remove(to_name)
                   mysend(from_sock, json.dumps({"action":"random", "results":[result,user]}))
```

and here is the random function from the client side:

```
elif my_msg[0:6]=="random":
                    mysend(self.s,json.dumps({"action":"random"}))
                    allresults = json.loads(myrecv(self.s))["results"]
                    result = allresults[0]
                    user=allresults[1]
                    if result: #==True
                        self.out_msg+="Peer Found\n"
                        self.out_msg+="Connecting you now...\n\n"
                        self.out_msg+='-----------------------------------\n'
                        if self.connect_to(user) == True:
                            self.state = S_CHATTING
                            if my_msg[7:]=="anon":
                                self.out_msg += 'Connected to anonymous user. Chat away!\n\n'
                            else:
                                self.out_msg += 'Connect to ' + user + '. Chat away!\n\n'
                            self.out_msg += '-----------------------------------\n'
                        else:
                            self.out_msg += 'An error occurred, please try again.\n'
                    else:
                        self.out_msg+="Peer not found, please try again later"
```

and

```
 if len(peer_msg) > 0:
                peer_msg = json.loads(peer_msg)
                consent=False
                if peer_msg["action"] == "connect":
                    self.connect_to(peer_msg["from"])
                    self.set_state(S_CHATTING)
                elif peer_msg["action"]=="consent":
                    self.out_msg += "A random user wants to connect with you?\n"
                    self.out_msg += "Would you like to accept the connection? (y or n)\n"
                    while my_msg != "y" and my_msg!="n":
                        self.out_msg += "Please only reply with 'y' or 'n'\n"
                    if my_msg=="y":
                        self.connect_to(peer_msg["from"])
                        self.set_state(S_CHATTING)
                        consent=True
                        mysend(self.s,json.dumps({"message":consent}))
                        self.out_msg+="Connecting you now...\n\n"
                    else:
                        consent=False
                mysend(self.s, json.dumps({"action":"random", "consent":consent}))
```

My system works normally as is, just these parts are difficult to get around.
Additionally the "lobby" file and functions in the server and client files don't fully function, yet I am having difficulty finding the bug myself.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question?  Currently you're kind of asking for a code review, which is wayyy too broad for Stack Overflow.  Asking a specific question about your encryption issues would make this more likely to be on topic.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark sorry, I'm pretty new here, will make an edit to ask

Comment: That edit didn't make it a whole lot better. SO is for specific questions only, not for requests for help or for use as an online debugger. The idea is that you ask a question that may be of help to others in the future (by searching for the terms / tags in your favorite search engine, for instance); good questions are not just useful to a particular user.